# Is there a C++ graphing library?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, graphing

Is there a C++ graphing library that can display visual graphs (such as hyperbolas and parabolas and linear equations) based on the equation it is given and that is cross platform? Or am I just asking for too much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take your question step by step.

1. "based on the equation [that] it is given" This would require you to write an expression parser; C++ cannot interpret equations "on the fly" without you writing a procedure to do so. For this, I recommend you look at [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) (go straight to the example RPN calc to get the idea).
2. For the libraries, you can get any GUI toolkit for C++; there are dozens; the recommendation for QT is probably the most honest one. Check also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit). You need *any* toolkit which will provide you with a *canvas* where you can *paint* or *render* lines or splines. This is not trivial, but also not difficult.

Your program would probably work as follows:

1. Get a mathematical expression (or the parameters for a known function; like the axes and center of an ellipse).
2. Generate a set of points (this is done with a loop in C++)
3. Pack those points and sent them to the *paint* or *render* method of your toolkit (with the appropriate scaling/normalization

Again, this is not trivial but not difficult either.

You are reinventing the wheel, but I commend you for that.

Cheers,

J.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products). It might have some graph capabilities. And there is [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). It's very extensive, so it might be a bit too complex for your needs though. It is cross-platform and there is a C++ API.

Comment: Qt does not have one of it's own.  However, there is an open source library at http://qwt.sourceforge.net/ that is very complete and easy to use.  For 3d charts, look at http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 1):

[MathGL](http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/) have expression parser and can plot function specified by textual formula (with a lot of special function included). Also you can create data set, fill it by formula and plot indirect functions (like ellipse, a*x^2+b*x^2=1).

Comment: +1: Wow, never found this before. Looks easy, and extremely fancy `:O`

Answer (score 0):

If all you are interested in is the final output, rather than the programming side of things; you might want to try interfacing with something like gnuplot ( http://www.gnuplot.info/ ).

If you're interested in more, I'd recommend looking at their 'Links' page. This offers a bunch of either interface libraries and re-implementations (mostly for non-C languages from what I can see).

Hope that helps.